# Django: Track changes in models

Tags: python, django, logging, cassandra

I want to track changes in the model, basically log every function in views.py.. so that whatever changes are made to the model are reflected in the log file.

**views.py**

```
def func_detail(func):
     @wraps(func)
     def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log', filemode='a',
                      format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                      datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                      level=logging.DEBUG)
         print("Inside wrapper. Calling method %s now..."%(func.__name__))
         r = func(*args, **kwargs)
         logging.getLogger(__name__)
         return r
     return func_wrapper

class UsersViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    @func_detail
    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        users = get_object_or_404(Mytable, name=pk)
        serializer = CheckSerializer(users, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            logging.info("Updated required data")
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

**models.py**

class Mytable(DjangoCassandraModel):
    name = columns.Text(primary_key=True)
    email = columns.Text()
    password = columns.Text()
    creation_date = columns.DateTime(default=datetime.datetime.today())
    modified_on = columns.DateTime(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

In Views.py:
I want to do something like this:

```
def func_detail(func):
     @wraps(func)
     def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log', filemode='a',
                      format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                      datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                      level=logging.DEBUG)
         if func.__name__ == 'list':
             print("This is all the list of objects created by you")
         elif func.__name__ == 'create':
             print("New user added in %s.%s" %(table.__name__, field.__name__))
         elif func.__name__ == 'retrieve':
             print("Tried retrieving pk %s" %(pk))
         elif func.__name__ == 'update':
             print("Updated model fields %s from table %s" %(field.__name__, table.__name__))
         elif func.__name__ == 'partial_update':
             print("Updated partial data from table %s in fields %s" %(table.__name__, field.__name__))

         # print("Inside wrapper. Calling method %s now..."%(func.__name__))
         r = func(*args, **kwargs)
         logging.getLogger(__name__)
         return r
     return func_wrapper
```

For example: If I make changes to my "name" field from 'abc' to 'xyz', it should reflect that changes has been made to the "name" field from 'abc' to 'xyz'. I don't have to use any third party packages. Only add few lines of code in 'def func_detail' that would dynamically track changes and update. I am very new to django/python, if anybody has any idea then please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use django signal 
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/. On ```post_save``` or check any other event, you can actually log or do whatever action u want to perform.

Comment: Is there not any other way to do this? except using signals?

Comment: I couldn't find anything but if not signal then you have to write code when you upsert data into the model.